# Get the subcategories of the current product category in Woocommerce archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy-terms

I'm trying to Show subcategories (not subsubcategories,etc) under current category in Woocommerce like  this Web: http://www.qs-adhesivos.es/app/productos/productos.asp?idioma=en

For Example, Construction is the category, and Sealants & adhesives, waterproofing, plyurethane foams… are subcategories.

Sealants & Mastics is the category, and ACETIC SILICONE SEALANT, NEUTRAL SILICONE SEALANT, ACRYLIC SEALANT… are subcategories…

Already have an archive-product.php in a woocommerce folder under my child theme.

Already tried some code and it applies but it's not what I want.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The following code will display the formatted linked product subcategories from current product category for product category archive pages:

```
if ( is_product_category() ) {

    $term_id  = get_queried_object_id();
    $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

    // Get subcategories of the current category
    $terms    = get_terms([
        'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
        'hide_empty'  => true,
        'parent'      => get_queried_object_id()
    ]);

    $output = '<ul class="subcategories-list">';

    // Loop through product subcategories WP_Term Objects
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

        $output .= '<li class="'. $term->slug .'"><a href="'. $term_link .'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';
    }

    echo $output . '</ul>';
}
```

Tested and works.

---

**USAGE EXAMPLES:**

1) You can use this code directly in `archive-product.php` template file.

2) You can embed the code in a function, replacing the last line `echo $output . '</ul>';` by `return $output . '</ul>';`, as for shortcodes, the display is always returned.

3) You can embed the code using action hooks like `woocommerce_archive_description`:

```
// Displaying the subcategories after category title
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'display_subcategories_list', 5 ); 
function display_subcategories_list() {
    if ( is_product_category() ) {

        $term_id  = get_queried_object_id();
        $taxonomy = 'product_cat';

        // Get subcategories of the current category
        $terms    = get_terms([
            'taxonomy'    => $taxonomy,
            'hide_empty'  => true,
            'parent'      => $term_id
        ]);

        echo '<ul class="subcategories-list">';

        // Loop through product subcategories WP_Term Objects
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $term_link = get_term_link( $term, $taxonomy );

            echo '<li class="'. $term->slug .'"><a href="'. $term_link .'">'. $term->name .'</a></li>';
        }

        echo '</ul>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

To display it after the category description, change the hook priority from **`5`** to **`20`** in:

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'display_subcategories_list', 5 );
```

like:

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'display_subcategories_list', 20 );
```

Comment: And where I need to put it? in function.php?

Comment: And what about: } elseif (!woocommerce_product_subcategories(array('before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start(false), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end(false)))) { in archive-product.php ?

Comment: Hi, first of all, many thanks for your answers and help. But is not working what I want. I should explain best. See OP again.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I made a mistake explaining what I want. Should I open new question and let this as before? Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for the perfect code.