# Undefined offset: 1 error while trying to change woocommerce breadcrumbs

Tags: php, woocommerce, offset

I need to show category and subcategory in Woocommerce breadcrumbs, so I tried following code but get ***Undefined offset: 1*** php error:

```
 // Woocommerce product categories in breadcrumbs

add_filter('x_breadcrumbs_data', 'post_parent_trail', 9999999, 2);
function post_parent_trail ($crumbs, $args) {
    if ( is_singular('product') ) {
        global $product;
        $category = get_the_terms( $product->ID, 'product_cat' );

        if ( count( $category ) > 0 ) {

            $cat_array             = array();
            $cat_array[1]['label'] = $category[1]->name;
            $cat_array[1]['url']   = get_term_link( $category[1]->term_id );
            $cat_array[2]['label'] = $category[0]->name;
            $cat_array[2]['url']   = get_term_link( $category[0]->term_id );

            array_splice($crumbs, 2, 0, $cat_array);
        }
    }
    return $crumbs;  
}
```

Could you please guide me to solve this issue?

Comment: `count( $category ) > 0` makes sure there are more than 0 elements (alternative: at least 1). This does not imply the existance of more than 1 element. Default arrays are 0-index-based meaing first element has id `0`. Therefore executing `$category[1]->name` tries to access the 2nd element (which is not garanteed by `count( $category ) > 0`)

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57767843/get-the-subcategories-of-the-current-product-category-in-woocommerce-archives) might help